# Get all records from table even there is no records in associated table with conditions on both

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables as below.

**Store table**

```
store_id store_name
    1    abc
    2    bcd    
    3    cde
```

**Purchase table**

```
purchase_id  store_id   date
001     1           2013-07-10
002     1           2013-07-20

004     2           2013-07-20
005     2           2013-08-01
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT ss.store_id,ss.store_name,tt.transaction_id FROM stores ss LEFT JOIN Purchase pp left join   on (ss.store_id=pp.store_id)

WHERE ss.store_id IN (1,3)  AND ((pp.date >= '2013-07-05') AND (pp.date <= '2013-08-05'))
```

Showing output like:

```
Store_id store_name purchase_id

1        abc        001
2        abc        002
```

I need output like:

```
Store_id store_name purchase_id

1        abc        001
2        abc        002
3        cde        NULL
```

Please suggest solution.Thank you.

Got the solution:

```
SELECT ss.store_id,ss.store_name,tt.transaction_id FROM stores ss 
LEFT JOIN Purchase pp left join   on (ss.store_id=pp.store_id) 
AND ((pp.date >= '2013-07-05') AND (pp.date <= '2013-08-05'))
WHERE ss.store_id IN (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are limiting the query to **search for the rows hvaing store_id (1,3)**

Removed the clause, 
Try this::

```
SELECT 
ss.store_id,
ss.store_name,
tt.transaction_id 
FROM stores ss 
LEFT JOIN Purchase pp left join   on (ss.store_id=pp.store_id)

WHERE (pp.date >= '2013-07-05') AND (pp.date <= '2013-08-05')
```

Comment: But i need to get records from store 1 and 3 (WHERE ss.store_id IN (1,3))

Comment: This contradicts your desired output, if you can change the output you desire

Comment: basically i need to show purchase from selected store . if a selected stores don't have any purchase within selected dates then it should show as 0 purchase for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your where clausule excludes NULL values. Add OR  IS NULL for date and that id in where...